# Magento: Bundle product error with Add to cart

Tags: magento, bundle, addition, product, cart

I do not understand why some times in the bundle products, the button "add to cart" does not work. (seems only with radio button)

By clicking does not open the shopping cart page.
If I do Ctrl + F5 and try again, it works.

How can I fix? I have some customers reporting this issue.

Regards,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a Javascript error on your page is causing this. Open your Console in your Web Developer toolbar to check for Javascript issues - once this is fixed, your add to cart on the bundled products page will work again.